# Passing own struct into opengl es 2.0 shader

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-lighting

I want to try a lighting example from the book OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide. In the shader they have made two structures.

```
struct directional_light   
{  

    vec3 direction; // normalized light direction in eye space  
    vec3 halfplane; // normalized half-plane vector  

    vec4 ambient_color;
    vec4 diffuse_color;
    vec4 specular_color;
};

struct material_properties 
{ 
    vec4 ambient_color; 
    vec4 diffuse_color; 
    vec4 specular_color; 
    float specular_exponent;
};
```

They have also made two uniforms, based on these structures.

```
uniform  material_properties u_material_properties;   
uniform directional_light u_directional_light;
```

The problem is, I do not know how to pass own structures into the actual shader.

I want to create the same structures in my main code and pass the objects into the shader. How is this possible?

Regards
Niclas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't, OpenGL ES doesn't have that functionality, to upload you have to get the location of each of your nested variables and call glUniform* on each of them.

For example:

```
GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_material_properties.ambient_color");
glUniform4f(loc, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: Do you know how I pass in variables? Lets say I have a vec3 in my shader : u_directional_light.direction. 
I am trying to pass in a GLfloat array but it doesnt seem to work.

uniforms[UNIFORM_DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT_DIRECTION] = glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_directional_light.direction");  

GLfloat na_ambient_color[] = {0.0,1.0,0.0};  

glUniform1fv(UNIFORM_DIRECTIONAL_LIGHT_DIRECTION, 1, (GLfloat *) na_ambient_color);

Comment: You need to use glUniform3fv for that. And glUniform4fv for vec4's, etc.

Comment: how to access if there a array of structures, like : "uniform directional_light lights[8];" ?

Comment: i assume , "GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "lights[0].ambient_color");  ?