# Passing an array of structs into OpenGL ES 2.0 shader

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-lighting

I want to implement some kind of lighting. And i'm making a struct, that contains light sourse properties in vertex shader:

```
struct Light
{
    vec4 color;
    vec4 pos;
    ...
};
```

In my app i want to have several light sources. So i put:

```
uniform Light[10];
```

How can i then load these uniforms from the app ? Is it a good approach or better to have:

```
uniform vec4 LightColor[10];
uniform vec4 LightPos[10];
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing own struct into opengl es 2.0 shader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110123/passing-own-struct-into-opengl-es-2-0-shader)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't pass structures to OpenGL ES shaders.
Please check this SO discussion that seems to confirm it:

[Passing own struct into opengl es 2.0 shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110123/passing-own-struct-into-opengl-es-2-0-shader)

I think it's safer to use your second proposal based on the arrays of vec4 uniforms.